# Why Rails autoload failed with the file is there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autoload, ruby-grape

I am setting up `Grape` on `Rails 4.1`. I am putting it inside `lib` according to http://funonrails.com/2014/03/building-restful-api-using-grape-in-rails/ .

I'd like to put helper methods in separated files, file structure is like following:

```
lib
 |--- api
    |--- root.rb
    |--- helpers
        |--- base_helper.rb
```

And inside `root.rb`, API is defined:

```
module API
  class Root < Grape::API
    formatter :json, Grape::Formatter::Jbuilder

    helpers API::BaseHelper
  end
end
```

Content of `base_helper.rb` is just simple:

```
module API
  module BaseHelper
    def test
      "I am a test helper"
    end
  end
end
```

When I fire up the application, I get:

```
/Users/Larry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@maleskine/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:481:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant BaseHelper, expected /Users/Larry/Gallows/jianshu.io/maleskine/lib/api/helpers/base_helper.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

But `base_helper.rb` is actually in the right path mentioned in the error.

And if I remove `helpers API::BaseHelper`, `autoload` could find `BaseHelper` correctly.

Why is that? What have I done wrong?

Comment: What is the contents of `lib/api/helpers/base_helper.rb` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging into Rails source code, I found the problem.

First, since the helper file is inside `helpers` folder, the file should be defined inside `Helpers` module:

```
module API
  module Helpers
    module BaseHelper
      def test
        "I am a test helper"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Second, `API::Helpers::BaseHelper` has the path suffix `api/helpers/base_helper`, so make sure `"#{Rails.root}/lib/" is inside your autoload path. Then`ActiveSupport` will find it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your BaseHelper is inside the `API` module. It should be defined like this:

```
module API
  module BaseHelper
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it is inside API. I just updated the main post.

Comment: I think it's because it's inside `helpers`.

Comment: Yes it's only of the problem. Just post an answer down there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
helpers API::BaseHelper
```

to

```
helpers ::API::BaseHelper
```

to specify absolutely the class you're trying to load.